# DataFrame set up using Dicts, Unexpected Setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am scraping each of these columns off of a website using XPATH. When I am finised pulling off all the columns, I am trying to put them together in one group of columns and then into a dataframe. I am following instructions I found online exactly, but am getting the image below instead of a normal table. What is going on here?

Also, I organized them in lists and created the dataframe from items the first time I attempted this, but then all of my columns were list and I could not change them to integers so I could do some group-by analysis on them.

Please help!

[image]

```
apt_data = {'Street': [street],
              'House_Number': [house_number],
              'Neighborhood': [areas],
              'Rent': [result_price_info],
              'Listing': [listing],
              'Number of Photos': [num_photos],
              'Rooms': [room_info],
              'Total Area': [size_info],
              'Year Built': [year_info],
              'Floor': [floor_info],
              'Material': [material_info],
              'Item Type': [type_info],
              'Last Updated': [update_info]
            }

# Organize into a Pandas Dataframe
apt_search = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(apt_data)
apt_search
```

Comment: It seems some nested lists, try change `'Street': [street]` to `'Street': street` - remove all `[]`

Comment: @jezrael, thank you for your suggestion. You were exactly rigth and answered within just a couple minutes! The person I was copying was creating their data inline, while I was pulling mine from the web into lists. Then, whe he was putting his data into lists, I was, in effect, trying to make lists of my lists or nesting lists, as you called it.

Comment: Thank you again for your quick answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is problem nested lists.

So need remove `[]` like:

```
'Street': [street]
```

to:

```
'Street': street
```

for all `list`s in `dictionary`.